# How is the title of "National treasure" attained?

Tags: japan, hinomaru-sumo

Ushio Hinomaru is one of the "National treasures", with the special title of "Onimaru Kinutsuna", along with a bunch of other very strong wrestlers, but at how was the title awarded? 
[image]
Because Hinomaru ghosted at some point but still retained the title, How was that possible? How does it work and is it a lifetime kinda award?

Comment: It might be refering to this status https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_National_Treasure_(Japan)

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to read this but I think I found the answer. Hinomaru is someone who has the title 'National Treasure' because he

> has the potential to become a yokozuna. ([Wiki](http://hinomaruzumo.wikia.com/wiki/Ushio_Hinomaru#Abilities))

[Yokozuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makuuchi#Yokozuna) is the highest rank in sumo. 'National Treasure' is *more like a moniker or an informal title rather than a formal one that can be obtained*. It is not an official rank but a nickname and since only those with a potential to attain the highest rank are given this nickname, then whether or not he ghosted, *he still has the potential to become yokozuna*, hence he was able to keep the 'title'.

Comment: In the latest interhigh tournament Arc, Kunisaki Chihiro suprisingly won his matches against 2 National Treasures but still didnt recieved a Title, even thou he most definitely showed a lot of potential. (He even  personally nicknamed himself the "The National Treasure eater" ) but even after his awesome perfomance at the tournament,  he is still not considered a National treasure. There has to be a way that every one knows when someone becomes a National treasure and not just "an unofficial nickname" cause if that were the case he most definitely should have become one i guess.